# How to validate request parameter key in springs

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. Just want to know can we validate request parameters key.
I have used `RequestParam` as u can see, for eg  `@RequestParam(value= "sourceType")` here `value = "sourceType"` is my key, so if user enters `sourcety` which does not match the given key it gives `400` error with sourceType missing in url. Rather then giving `404` error, I want it only give sourceType missing in url or invalid sourceType? 
Here is my controller,

```
@Scope("request")
@RestController
public class GetOperatorSeries{
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOperatorSeries(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "mobno") long mobno,
            @RequestParam(value = "sourceType") String sourceType,
            @RequestParam(value = "responseType") String responseType)
{

}
```

Here is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web1="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="voiceBank" version="2.5">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testmemspring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testmemspring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/testmemspring-servlet.xml
           </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Here is my spring configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.one97.org" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="testSpring" class="com.one97.org.controller.TestSpring"
        scope="request">
    </bean>



    <bean id="internalViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>




</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your request param as optional. Then you can check it manually whether it exists or not. Depending on it you can show custom error message. For example -

```
@Scope("request")
@RestController
public class GetOperatorSeries{
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOperatorSeries(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "mobno") long mobno,
            @RequestParam(value = "sourceType", required=false) String sourceType,
            @RequestParam(value = "responseType") String responseType, Model model)
{

    if (sourceType == null) {
     model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Source Type is missing");
     return "viewName"; // Now show the error message in view. You can also add this error as flash attribute. You can also show a new error page.


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, i tried this but still getting the same error. Here is the output HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /TestMemSpring/test. Reason:

    Required String parameter 'sourceType' is not present

Comment: Hey, its working fine. Actually i was not using required=false. Thanks for the help. Kindly, please elaborate what does this required=false do?

Comment: Request param required false means it is not mandatory. You can provide it or not. By default the value of required is true. So if you don't provide the request param at your request it will give error HTTP 400. So to make a request param optional you need to use required=false.

Comment: Hi Sir, on passing this url localhost:8080/MemcachedData/test?mobno=8877546122&sourceType= ##&responseType=11. getting empty value on passing "#".

Comment: It is because # has a special meaning at url. There are some other characters those have special meaning when being used at url including &. So if you want to use any of the special characters you need to escape. To escape # you need to use %26. You can see a full list here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: if end user tries to enter #  in url , then how would i validate this?

Comment: I guess ## character does not contain any meaning at url. So if any user use such character you well get it as empty. You can treat it as nothing and take action whatever you need. I mean you can consider such character as nothing or empty. One more thing usually we use # character to a link to mean no url at all.

Comment: @ Jahangir Alam for now i am checking empty value,which is working fro me, but still i dont understand what is the meaning of # in url as rest all special characters can be read easily but on passing # it returns empty value

Comment: @ Jahangir Alam Hi sir, can you please share a regular expression which only accept + and valid digits. Actually i want validation on mobile number which only accept + and valid digits

Comment: "\\+?\\d{8,13}" set the length as you need instead of 8 to 13

Comment: @ Jahangir Alam It's not working, in this case it is accepting 0000000000 also which is not a valid number and neither it is accepting +91 also.